# distributed tensorflow clarification

Tags: tensorflow, tf-slim

Is my understanding correct that [`model_deploy`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/deployment/model_deploy.py) lets the user train a model using multiple devices on a single machine? The basic premise seems that the clone devices do variable sharing and variables get distributed to param servers in a round-robin fashion.

On the other hand [distributed tensorflow framework](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed) enables the user to train a model through a cluster. A Cluster lets the user train a model using multiple devices across multiple servers.

I think the Slim documentation is very slim and the point has been raised couple of times already:  [Configuration/Flags for TF-Slim across multiple GPU/Machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41229450/configuration-flags-for-tf-slim-across-multiple-gpu-machines)

Thank you.

Comment: You can guess by number of "TODO's" in that file that it's a work in progress. It builds on top of Distributed TF API. If you want to use something that's ready for prime-time, you are better off using the core distributed tensorflow framework

Comment: Yes, looks like it is a WIP. Thank you for your response.